# three.js, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, html, three.js, blender

I'm trying to load a json file in html using three.js but I'm running into the following error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
THREE.ObjectLoader.parseObject @ three.js:13066
THREE.ObjectLoader.parse @ three.js:12706
(anonymous function) @ three.js:12677
(anonymous function) @ three.js:11761
```

I used the three.js (71) plugin for Blender (2.75a) to export from FBX to json.

I tried switching from ObjectLoader to JSONLoader, but I get a similar error except that is cannot read property 'length' instead. Any idea?

I'm using the example from https://github.com/master-atul/blender3js/dis/index.html

Here's a link to the json file I am having problem with: 
http://we.tl/8a3rxgpqr5

Below is a snippet of the json loading code:

```
var characterGenerator = function () {
  var init = function () {
    var defer = q.defer();
    var mesh = null;
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

    loader.load("assets/test_igor.json", function (geometry, materials) {
      for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
        var m = materials[i];
        m.skinning = true;
      }
      mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
      //mesh.rotation.y = 90;
      mesh.animator = function (animeName) {
        var selected = _.find(geometry.animations, {'name': animeName});
        var animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh, selected);
        animation.play();
      };
      defer.resolve(mesh);
    });
    return defer.promise;
  };

  return {
    init: init
  }
}();
```

Comment: Could you please show some of the code you're using to load the json file ? I don't think anyone will have enough information to help you without more details...

Comment: Updated the question with a link to the file I'm trying to get working and a code snippet. I must say that it works with the "boxguy.json", but it doesn't with my "test_igor.json".

Comment: Then it's much likely a problem with the format of the test_igor.json file... Did you generate both files yourself ? Do you know what Three.js needs ?

Comment: boxguy.json already came with the example, test_igor.json was the file I generated. I installed the plugin in Blender the standard way, and checked a few boxes (vertices, normals, UVs, faces, apply modifiers, face materials, vertex colors, mix colors, morph animation, copy textures) before hitting the export button.
Here's a link to the file: http://we.tl/8a3rxgpqr5